# Objective-C Mapview crash on IPA (appstore version) Xcode 9 work well

Tags: objective-c, xcode, crash, ipa

All is in the title, everything is ok in Xcode 9.
Application is ok for Apple, but all my mapwiew make application crash after download it from the Appstore.

Xcode 9 - Objective-C - When running it with my iPhone SE or iPad 2 from Xcode, everything work well.
Appstore version crash on both.

Thanks to help me understand something.

Here my device Logs from Xcode (first part) :

```
Incident Identifier: C2CCC5F8-01ED-4295-AE93-578642B19E99
CrashReporter Key:   4b962ec4fbb937bae60eb5d2ed98278c01a3d76b
Hardware Model:      iPhone8,4
Process:             Espace Sexualité Jeunes [1630]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/39B1D2C1-DC8E-4FB9-AAB9-51F04D287209/Espace Sexualité Jeunes.app/Espace Sexualité Jeunes
Identifier:          com.espacesexualitejeunes.paco
Version:             1.0.1 (1.0.1)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.espacesexualitejeunes.paco [742]


Date/Time:           2018-02-08 12:49:31.0908 -0400
Launch Time:         2018-02-08 12:49:18.8182 -0400
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.2.1 (15C153)
Baseband Version:    6.30.04
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x185fba364 __exceptionPreprocess + 124
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x185200528 objc_exception_throw + 55
2   CoreFoundation                  0x185fba2ac +[NSException raise:format:] + 115
3   UIKit                           0x18fbdc270 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 371
4   UIKit                           0x18fbdc0e4 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 103
5   UIKit                           0x18fa2e6c0 -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 135
6   UIKit                           0x18fbdc3ac UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 687
7   UIKit                           0x18fbdc524 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1063
8   UIKit                           0x18fbdc0e4 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 103
9   UIKit                           0x18fa2da34 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1167
10  UIKit                           0x18f80ac74 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 371
11  UIKit                           0x18f5b897c -[UIViewController loadView] + 175
12  UIKit                           0x18f49b790 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 183
13  UIKit                           0x18f49b6c0 -[UIViewController view] + 27
14  UIKit                           0x18f61eb1c -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 1147
15  UIKit                           0x18f541c4c -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 711
16  UIKit                           0x18f541890 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 163
17  UIKit                           0x18f541790 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 187
18  UIKit                           0x18f498f00 -[UIView+ 52992 (CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1275
19  QuartzCore                      0x189ffd998 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 183
20  QuartzCore                      0x18a001b20 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed+ 1207072 (CA::Transaction*) + 331
21  QuartzCore                      0x189f6e36c CA::Context::commit_transaction+ 602988 (CA::Transaction*) + 335
22  QuartzCore                      0x189f95b90 CA::Transaction::commit+ 764816 () + 539
23  UIKit                           0x18f6fcb10 _UIApplicationFlushRunLoopCATransactionIfTooLate + 171
24  UIKit                           0x18fdf3bb8 __handleEventQueueInternal + 5543
25  UIKit                           0x18fdec7c0 __handleHIDEventFetcherDrain + 151
26  CoreFoundation                  0x185f6297c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 23
27  CoreFoundation                  0x185f628fc __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 87
28  CoreFoundation                  0x185f62184 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 203
29  CoreFoundation                  0x185f5fd5c __CFRunLoopRun + 1047
30  CoreFoundation                  0x185e7fe58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 435
31  GraphicsServices                0x187d2cf84 GSEventRunModal + 99
32  UIKit                           0x18f4ff67c UIApplicationMain + 235
33  Espace Sexualité Jeunes         0x10456d0c8 0x104564000 + 37064
34  libdyld.dylib                   0x18599c56c start + 3


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000185acc2e8 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185be12f8 pthread_kill$VARIANT$mp + 396
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000185a3afbc abort + 140
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001851d8068 __cxa_bad_cast + 0
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001851d8210 default_unexpected_handler+ 8720 () + 0
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000185200810 _objc_terminate+ 34832 () + 124
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001851f054c std::__terminate(void (*)+ 107852 ()) + 16
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001851f0158 __cxa_rethrow + 144
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001852006e8 objc_exception_rethrow + 44
9   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185e7fec4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 544
10  GraphicsServices                0x0000000187d2cf84 GSEventRunModal + 100
11  UIKit                           0x000000018f4ff67c UIApplicationMain + 236
12  Espace Sexualité Jeunes         0x000000010456d0c8 0x104564000 + 37064
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018599c56c start + 4

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000185accd80 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185bdeeec _pthread_wqthread + 884
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185bdeb6c start_wqthread + 4

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185bdeb68 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185bdeb68 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000185aab568 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000185aab3e0 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185f62308 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185f5fed4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1424
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185e7fe58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
5   Foundation                      0x00000001868b5594 -[NSRunLoop+ 50580 (NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6   Foundation                      0x00000001868d49ac -[NSRunLoop+ 178604 (NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 96
7   UIKit                           0x00000001900697b8 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136
8   Foundation                      0x00000001869b70f4 __NSThread__start__ + 996
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185be02b4 _pthread_body + 308
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185be0180 _pthread_body + 0
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185bdeb74 thread_start + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x00000001c42e0e37
    x4: 0x00000001851f5afd   x5: 0x000000016b89b490   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0xffffffffffffffec
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x0000000185be55e0  x11: 0x0000000000000003
   x12: 0xffffffffffffffff  x13: 0x0000000000000001  x14: 0x0000000185a5153f  x15: 0x0000000000000010
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x00000000ffffffff  x18: 0xfffffff01249925c  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x00000001b7093b80  x21: 0x000000016b89b490  x22: 0x0000000000000303  x23: 0x00000001b7093c60
   x24: 0x00000001c4017880  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x0000000000000001  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x000000016b89baf0   fp: 0x000000016b89b3f0   lr: 0x0000000185be12f8
    sp: 0x000000016b89b3c0   pc: 0x0000000185acc2e8 cpsr: 0x00000000
```

Comment: How are you showing your map views?

Comment: Storyboard - MKMapView in UIViewController

Give me more details about your question please...

Comment: I just see my first crash log wasn't the good one... this is the good one, really sorry !

Comment: Please provide some code for what is displaying the map view

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my problem: I'm stupid!

I forgot to include the MapKit.framework in my App. I re-upload it to the Appstore and everything work perfectly now.